# Android Intents - putExtra, what happens with multiple occurances?

Tags: android, android-intent, put

Let's say that I'm using an intent to get info back to the main class that called the current activity.

What would happen if say, I had two methods that might overlap the same field, like:

```
myIntent.putExtra("returnVal1",1000);
 // many lines of code, later on...
myIntent.putExtra("returnVal1",5);
```

Would the "returnVal1" be updated to 5 in the intent, will it stay at 1000, or will this cause runtime crashes?

Thanks in advance, sent from mobile, not at a computer with eclipse atm or I would test myself!

Comment: The documentation isn't clear about that, but I would recommend to test it, if you need it next time. Or are you developing on your mobile phone?

Comment: I am testing it, will post you the result :)

Comment: i was gonna say that try urself but then i read the "sent from mobile"... :) well it will be updated...

Comment: I'm away from civilization at the moment, and musing about my code from the warm glow of my droid under the stars  :-)  But yes, I cannot test for myself at the moment.  Has anyone ever tried this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will overwrite it. The extra attributes are essentially a single-value hash: new values overwrite any existing values.

Comment: does it overwrite same memory location or different, I think a new one, since the odl and new values can be of different lengths